# Excel advanced filter field within 2 dates

Tags: excel, date

i've a BIG table called "big", where first column is a Date (of creation).

I'd like to show in another sheet all the entries where date i between 2 given ones.

I manage to do Greater, Greater or equal and so on with Advanced Filters.

In the criteria date cell i simply put:

```
=">="&B2
```

Where B2 is my Date1 (the initial date I'd like for the range).

In C3 i've another date (Surely bigger than B2!) and I don't know what should I write instead of that formula to have something like

```
B2 <= DATE <= C3
```

And filter dates that are in this range.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add more details? Why not just do `=">="&B2&"<="&C3`?

Comment: First i didn't think at such a formula, but it doesn't works. What details are missing,

Answer (score 1):

I did it:

To make an "and" statement in Advanced filter, you need 2 fields with same label a the same row, ending with more column than the original data fields:

```
DATE          DATE           ...         ....
>Startdate    <Enddate
```

Selecting all these criteria will do an AND statemant. If you make 2 rows with two date citeria, will be an OR statement.

I don't know if a "monocell" formula exists.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the userform to filter it?

I developed a template to filter products between two selected dates using the userform. The filtered products are listed in the listbox. The selected products from the listbox are copied to the other worksheet.

[image]

To make the date selection easier, I added a date userform (second userform) instead of a calendar control. When clicked the textboxes on the main userform, the date userform is opened and the user can easily select the date.

[Source codes and sample file here](https://eksi30.com/filter-products-between-two-dates-with-vba-userform/)